# Density Function to Distribution Function

Tags: probability

Scratching my head over how from the given density function, we got the distribution function below... anybody has any idea?

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & x\le-1\\
c, & -1< x\le1\\
0, & x > 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\mathbf F(x) = \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}
$$

Shouldn't this just have been an integral of $ f(x) $ which would give $\frac{1}{2}x$ ?

Of course, c has already been solved to be 1/2

Thanks in advance for any assistance (if possible a step by step solution of this as well) please.

Comment: The value of the distribution function $F$ at any _number_ $t$ is the _area_ under the density function $f(x)$ up to $t$, that is, $$F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ You need to learn to distinguish between the _integral_ of $f(x)$ and the _antiderivative_ of $f(x)$. The latter is $x/2$ in this case, while $F(x) = (x+1)/2$ _only_ for $x \in (-1,1)$. For $x \geq 1$, $F(x) = 1$ and for $x < -1$, $F(x) = 0$.

Comment: thank you.  That makes complete sense to distinguish between the integral and the anti-derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$ then
$$
F(x) = \int_{-1}^x c \, du = \Big[ cu \Big]_{u=-1}^{u=x} = cx - c(-1) = c(x+1).
$$
If you know that $c=\dfrac12$ then you've got it.

Notice that that answer is valid only when $-1\le x\le 1$.

Comment: ah, I was integrating with discreet values and not from -1 to x... which should have been the case.  Thank you.  How would you calculate the E[X] from the given $f(x)$?  And the Var(X)?  There were a couple of parts more that I'm not sure how to solve but I do have the answers, just trying to see the reasoning 
Determine $P(X\le-1/2)$ and Determine $P(|X|\ge1/2)$  and thank you for the help!

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathbb E(X) = \int_{-1}^1 x f(x)\, dx$ $\displaystyle=\int_{-1}^1 cx \, dx$ $=0$.  We don't need anything outside the interval $[-1,1]$ since the density is $0$ there.  For the variance, integrate $c(x-0)^2\,dx$ from $-1$ to $1$.  The number $0$ appears in that rule because it's the expected value.

Answer (score 2):

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt=\int_{-1}^xc   dt=$$
$$\int_{-1}^x\dfrac{1}{2}dt=\dfrac{1}{2}(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{2}x+\dfrac{1}{2}$$

for $x\leq 1$