# Determine the Distribution Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Another density function to Distribution function that has me stumped again.  This time, I might be going wrong on my intervals.

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1, & -1<x\le0\\
1-x, & 0< x\le1\\
0, & otherwise\\
\end{cases}
$$

I know now that to get $F(x)$ I should integrate these two density functions. 
so $\int_{-1}^x x+1 dx$ which gives me $\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x + \frac{1}{2}$ which is fine, as that would be between the interval $-1<x\le0$

For the second interval (from $0<x\le1$), $\int_0^x 1-x dx$ which gives me $-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x$

however the answer says it should be $-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x + \frac{1}{2}$ can someone please help me out .. where is this extra 1/2 coming from?  Is my interval selection wrong or am I not integrating properly?

Thank you so much in advance for your help and your time.

Comment: -1 In response to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/364969/15941), I commented "  
"The value of the distribution function $F$ at any number $t$ is the area under the density function $f(x)$ up to $t$, that is, $$F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\,\mathrm dx."$$ Which part of this statement did you not understand, and why are you writing $\int_0^x 1-x dx$ instead of $$\int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int_{-1}^t f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}+\int_0^t 1-x \,\mathrm dx ??$$

Comment: Thanks for your input :-)  I think the two questions were different in a way that in this one, you have two functions to worry about, for - 1 to 0 and for 0 to 1, and I figured integrating them from -1 to x and 0 to x (because they are different functions) would give the response for that respective case.  I appreciate your intention (to educate) , though your answer is not clear. -1 to t ... is split in two parts, -1 to 0 and then 0 to 1.  The response below by Andre Nichols is far more explicit and clears things up a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, 
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt,$$
where $f$ is the density function.  If you prefer, you can write $\int_{-\infty}^x f(x)\,dx$. (The second notation can be confusing, since $x$ appears both as the dummy variable of integration and in the upper limit.)

Because our density function is given by different formulas in different places, we will have to be careful in evaluating the integral.

(i) Suppose that $-\infty\lt x\le -1$. Then $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x (0)\,dt=0$.

(ii) Suppose that $-1\lt x\le 0$. Then $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} (0)\,dt+\int_{-1}^x (t+1)\,dt=\frac{x^2}{2}+x+\frac{1}{2}$.

(iii) Suppose that $0\lt x\le 1$. Again, we integrate the density function from $-\infty$ to $x$. Let's not bother writing down the part from $-\infty$ to $-1$, there is nothing there. But there **is** stuff from $-1$ to $0$. So for $0\l x\le 1$, the  integral is $\int_{-1}^0 (1+t)\,dt +\int_0^x(1-t)\,dt$.
The part from $-1$ to $0$ gives $\frac{1}{2}$. The part from $0$ to $x$ gives $x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. Add.

(iv) Suppose that $x\gt 1$. The integral from $-\infty$ to $1$ is $1$, and the density is $0$ after that, so $F(x)=1$ for $x\gt 1$.

**Remark:** To see what is going on, it is useful to draw the density function. The graph is $0$ up to $x=-1$, then climbs linearly until it hits the value $1$ at $x=0$, then falls to $0$ at $x=1$, and then stays at $0$.  The function $F(x)$ gives the **area** under the curve from $-\infty$ to $x$.

This may help to answer answer your question.  Suppose we want to find the area under the curve from $-\infty$ to $x$, where $0\lt x\le 1$. We certainly don't just integrate $1-t$ from $0$ to $x$. We have to add in the area to the left of $x=0$. This area is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  Just to clarify, in part (ii) you said the integral of $\int_{-1}^x(t+1)dt = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} $  shouldn't that have been $  \frac{x^2}{2} + x + \frac{1}{2}$ ?  So finally, what we are doing at each interval, which makes sense because $F(x)$ is cumulative, is that we are adding up each of the previous intervals as we want the distribution by integrating from $-\infty$ to $x$.  
Am I correct in assuming that?  We are adding up the integral results?

Comment: @Amit: Thank you for catching it! Fixed.